# Display works when U-Boot loads but not with Arch Linux ARM

Tags: arch-linux, embedded, display, arm, u-boot

guys.
I installed Arch Linux ARM on my old Allwinner A31s tablet. I can use it via UART/serial console but I can't get the display to work. The tablet turns on, U-Boot loads and shows your submarine logo on the display but as soon as Arch Linux ARM starts loading the display stops working and shows nothing. The backlight stays on all the time. Up until now I can only use it via UART/serial console. Can anyone point me to the possible causes of this or any solution? I'm trying to win this battle of reviving an old tablet. This is the last step.

I'm using "ARMv7 Multi-platform" release.

Here are the fragments of my boot log about the display if it helps (full log here: https://pastebin.com/100U8phr)

```
------------------------------------------------------------
HELLO! BOOT0 is starting!
boot0 version : 3.1.0
reg_addr 0x01f00100 =0x00000000
reg_addr 0x01f00104 =0x00000000
reg_addr 0x01f00108 =0x00000000
reg_addr 0x01f0010c =0x00000000
reg_addr 0x01f00110 =0x00000000
reg_addr 0x01f00114 =0x00000000
[DRAM]ver 1.06 clk = 408
cpu 1 pmu 1
dram size =1024
sum=0xc0352551
src_sum=0xc0352551
Ready to disable icache.
Jump to secend Boot.
[ 0.207]

U-Boot 2011.09-rc1-00000-gfa2c354 (Sep 15 2014 - 09:28:49) Allwinner Technology

[ 0.216]version: 1.1.0
[ 0.229]pmbus: ready
[ 0.232]PMU: AXP221
[ 0.234]PMU: AXP22x found
[ 0.237]PMU: bat ratio = 100
[ 0.240]PMU: dcdc3 1260
[ 0.243]PMU: pll1 1008 Mhz
dcdc1_vol = 3000
dcdc2_vol = 1200
dcdc3_vol = 1260
dcdc4_vol = 1240
dcdc5_vol = 1500
aldo2_vol = 1800
aldo3_vol = 3000
eldo3_vol = 1200
find power_sply to end
fel key old mode
run key detect
no key found
no key input
dram_para_set start
dram_para_set end
[ 0.285]DRAM: 1 GiB
relocation Offset is: 15b12000
donn't initialize ther user_gpio (main_key:boot_init_gpio)
deu_mode1 not exist.
lcdgamma4iep for lcd1 not exist.
DRV_DISP_Init: opened
[ 0.572]fetch script data boot_disp.output_type fail
[ 0.577]fetch script data boot_disp.output_mode fail
[ 0.582]fetch script data boot_disp.auto_hpd fail
[ 0.587]lcd0_para.lcd_used=1
workmode = 0
[ 0.926]NAND: NAND_UbootInit
NAND_UbootInit start
NB1 : enter NAND_LogicInit
uboot:physical version: 2 19 20140617 1840
nand : get id_number_ctl fail, 1
uboot:nand info: a714dead ffff4a42 31c0 40704 5
not burn nand partition table!
[...................]
------------------------------------------------------------
[...................]
Loading Environment from FAT... Unable to use mmc 0:1...
EDID block 0: checksum error, retrying
EDID block 0: checksum error, retrying
EDID block 0: checksum error
Setting up a 1280x800 lcd console (overscan 0x0)
In: serial
Out: serial,vidconsole
Err: serial,vidconsole
Net: No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 2  1  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
Found U-Boot script /boot/boot.scr
[...................]
------------------------------------------------------------
[...................]
[ 0.087906] platform 1e40000.display-backend: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e20000.display-frontend
[ 0.087992] platform 1e40000.display-backend: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e00000.display-frontend
[ 0.088627] platform 1e50000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1c0d000.lcd-controller
[ 0.088752] platform 1e50000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1c0c000.lcd-controller
[ 0.088831] platform 1e50000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e40000.display-backend
[ 0.089401] platform 1e60000.display-backend: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e20000.display-frontend
[ 0.089484] platform 1e60000.display-backend: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e00000.display-frontend
[ 0.090087] platform 1e70000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1c0d000.lcd-controller
[ 0.090189] platform 1e70000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1c0c000.lcd-controller
[ 0.090266] platform 1e70000.drc: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1e60000.display-backend
[ 0.093537] kprobes: kprobe jump-optimization is enabled. All kprobes are optimized if possible.
[...................]
------------------------------------------------------------
[...................]
[[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mMulti-User System[0m.
[[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mGraphical Interface[0m.
[ 12.915755] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[ 12.926174] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[ 12.929155] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[ 12.940567] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[ 12.985526] rtl8xxxu 3-1:1.2 wlu1i2: renamed from wlan0
[ 13.646088] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x0e3da5b1

Arch Linux 6.2.1-1-ARCH (ttyS0)
alarm login:
------------------------------------------------------------
```